# Angular 17 material in the datepicker sets me one day behind

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular17

I've been trying to set the dates for days, in Angular view it shows me correctly with the pipe but upon insertion it gives me this 2024-03-04T23:00:00.000Z i set I set the 5th as the day though

I set 05/04/2024 and automatically set 2024-04-05